# Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury vs Redragon M711 Cobra: Which one is good for me?

Tags: mice

can some people please recommend which mouse would be better for my purpose listed below?

I use mainly Linux (Manjaro Linux), but sometimes I play games on Windows 11, like CS:GO, Asphalt 9, Minecraft, and Team Fortress 2 (yes, very diverse). I am a coder (mainly), and I sometimes play the games listed above. Please reply below if I need to list my specs or be more specific on what I would like my mouse to feature.

Comment: If your local store has both, test them out I guess. Mice are mostly personal prefference. I personally like the Battletron mouse you can get in the Action.

Comment: It's online. Can't get both because reasons.